# Explanation of the difference of code.. Subset recursive call

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand what the difference is under the hood between these codes:

```
class Solution {
    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        search(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0, nums);
        return output; 
    }

    private void search(List<Integer> state, int index, int[] nums){
        output.add((state));
        for(int i = index; i < nums.length; i++){
            state.add(nums[i]);
            search(state, i+1, nums);
            state.remove(state.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

which returns [[][][][][][]]

But

```
class Solution {
    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        search(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0, nums);
        return output; 
    }

    private void search(List<Integer> state, int index, int[] nums){
        output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(state));
        for(int i = index; i < nums.length; i++){
            state.add(nums[i]);
            search(state, i+1, nums);
            state.remove(state.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

returns a valid list of subset given an array.

Why do I need to wrap my state with a new ArrayList when adding to output?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: java.util.ArrayList implements java.util.List interface , with polymorphism of objects they can be more than one type by "extending" (another class or interface) or with interfaces on a class "implementing" or an interface "extending" another interface. Generics is more complicated <Integer> means the data contained must only be that of java.lang.Integer , that is called a "type safe check" e.g. <T> almost anything or for classes not "final class" , e.g.  <? extends java.util.ArrayList>   apart it extends java.util.AbstractList<E> E element is mainly document representation.

Comment: <? extends java.util.ArrayList> would be something like class MySpecialList extends java,util.ArrayList{  // arraylist is public  NOTE java.util.ArrayList implements java.util.List interface  therefore ArrayList IS A List

Comment: Of this . ."returns a valid list of subset given an array."..  I don't actually agree , it may be resolving bringing back the first entry of the level it finds by hierarchy is an Integer,not actually looking that deep except as "resolving" because it could contain Integer deeper because it found an aka List .I'm not sure how it internally holds onto its E elements in it.Rather than an extended class,it is able to treat the variables it stores as inner sub class to reach Integer,as close as it ever gets to finding Integer by "Java Reflection".it is possible to use super keyword on variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the `new`.

In the broken solution, one `new` occurs in `subsets`, which is only called once. The `search` method calls itself a bunch of times, but contains **zero** `new` statements. Finally, there's `outputs`, but that's a different concept here so we don't care much about it. Even disregarding that, that's only 1 `new` for a grand total of two.

**That means there is just the one list object**. You're re-using it every time. So,  That `state.add()` call? That adds to the one and only list that exists.  And, the `state.remove()` call also applies to the one and only list that exists.

Thus, your code:

1. Adds something to the list. Which starts off empty.
2. Recurses.
3. Removes that something from the list.

At the very deepest levels of recursing, your list contains plenty of stuff, but, it's all removed at the end. Crucially, your list-of-lists (`output`) just contains a reference to the same list over and over. As your one and only list ends up being empty, that one list that is repeatedly in `outputs` is that same empty list.

Here's how to think about it:

You build one house, and only one. You write its address on a piece of paper and hand it to a buddy to process (this is the `subsets` method's `new ArrayList<Integer>()` call).

Your buddy then walks over to the address, and, will:

1. Make a copy of the note with the address and stick it in a big folder (`outputs.add(state)`). **Not a copy of the house**, no, just a reference - i.e. a copy of its address.
2. Build a cupboard in the house. (`state.add(thing)`).
3. Make another copy of the note with the address and hand it to another buddy who is going to do similar things. All to the same house. You'll wait while your buddy does her thing.
4. You remove the cupboard from the house.
5. You do steps 2-4 a bunch of times.

Your buddy does the same 'algorithm', but, no matter how you slice this, this one house ends up with zero cupboards in it, and your big folder of outputs contains just a whole bunch of little notes, and each and every note has the exact same address on it. Which leads to a house that contains no cupboards. It used to - but it no longer does.

Contrast to the working snippets, which replaced:

1. Make a copy of the note with the address and stick it in a big folder.

with:

1. Find an empty spot of land and build a new house, then copy the exact state of the old house - whatever cupboards are in the main house, painstakingly copy that exactly to this newly built house. Then write the address of this newly built house on a note and stick that in a big folder.

In java parlance, all non-primitive values are **references** - they are not the value itself, but a pointer to it. Java is pass-by-value (i.e. anytime you call a method, all arguments are copied), but, what's copied is the reference. `.` and `[]` are the dereferencing operators: It's the equivalent of "walk over to the address on the note". `=` isn't - that overwrites notes with addresses.

Imagine a list with 5 million items on it. `listA = listB;` is very fast because it just copies the pointer, it doesn't copy all 5 million items. `new ArrayList<Integer>(someList)` hands a copy of the reference (a copy of the pointer that leads to whatever `someList` is currently pointing at) to that constructor of `ArrayList`. That constructor shallowly copies the entire list. That would take ~5 million steps.